# Do you order sequence logic by what step you are in, or what step you are transitioning to?

Tags: sequence, plc

After some internal discussions on this subject I was looking for some other opinions on this. For a simple sequence, using some standard ladder logic, you can have your sequence step bit at the start of a rung and have the rungs go down the page in order. You can have the transitions (usually move the step number you want to go to into an integer) at the end of the rung and they can also be in order. The problem comes when you have a non trivial sequence that does not flow through sequentially.

Do you organize your logic so the bits on the left (what step you are in) are in order, or do your organize it so your moves on the right (your transitions) are in order. When you have a transition to multiple steps, do you have multiple moves from one step bit, or do you have multiple bits triggering one move?

an example:

what you are after

```
in 6 and X go to step 10
in 7 and Y go to step 10
in 21 and Z go to step 10
```

ordered by what step you are in

```
XIC(step.6) and X mov 10
XIC(step.7) and Y mov 10
XIC(step.8)... 
...
XIC(step.21)and Z mov 10
```

ordered by transition

```
... mov 9
XIC(step.6)and X,XIC(step.7) and Y),XIC(step.21) and Z mov 10
...mov 11
```

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you look at Sequential Function Chart or Grafcet diagrams as a design tool, then implement your ladder logic based on the diagram.  If you look at the SFC simple transitions, you are sitting in a STEP and waiting for the next transition condition to go to the next step in the sequence.

Therefore, I would recommend implementing ladder logic as the "step" you are in, along with any transition condition logic, then setting the step value to the next step when that transition condition becomes true.

What's good about this is that you can see what "state" your "program" is in just by looking at the step number, rather than looking at the step number and figuring out which step is trying to transition to THAT step number to determine the state of your sequence.

Comment: So you are saying order the rungs by the step you are in, not the transition? What I am used to seeing is you have both an array of bits for what step you are in, and an integer. I agree a clear idea of what you are doing is good to have before you start. Nowadays you can program in SFC or in function block diagrams, why a lot of people still use ladder is a tricky question.

Comment: I'm just allowing for the possibility that you may want to skip steps or actually branch to one of N possible choices (e.g. a C switch statement, or in SFC-land, multiple transitions out of the same step).  If you keep all your logic step-centric, instead of transition-centric, the relay ladder logic gets a little more managable from a "state machine" stand-point.

Answer (score 1):

First have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_function_chart
Switch to the Italian version of that wiki page in which I put an example image and some more explanations.

First formalize your problem in a sequence of steps and transitions, than translate easily:

(pseudo-language just to understand logic)

If (STEP_0 = true) AND (transition_0 = true) -> RESET STEP_0 and SET STEP_1

If (STEP_1 = true) AND (transition_1 = true) -> RESET STEP_1 and SET STEP_2

and so on..